# Ionic cordova file transfer plugin not downloading file via HTTPS in android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I've been working on ionic project. The project uses various plugins including file transfer plugin.

**Problem**

When I install and run the app, it fails to download resources like image and audio from the api. When I debugged following error was shown:

```
{
    "code": 3,
    "source": "https://api.example.com/uploads/audio/011576657039579041.mp3",
    "target": "file:///data/user/0/com.myapp.snork/files/audio/011576657039579041.mp3",
    "http_status": null,
    "body": null,
    "exception": "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found."
}
```

I tested it on Android 6, 7 and 8, with no luck. it works in iOS. Can anybody tell me what might be gone wrong??

**What I have tried?**

- Removing and adding android platform again
- Removing and adding file transfer plugin again.

**My working Environment**

- @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
- ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
- @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.8
- Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.3.1
- Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
- Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1

**UPDATE**

The source URL - https://api.example.com/uploads/audio/011576657039579041.mp3 can be accessible directly via browser, so there is nothing wrong in source URL.

Is it due to **https** ??

Comment: Try adding this `<access origin="cdvfile://*" />` to your config.xml file.

Comment: @Kirubel, I already have `<access origin="*" />` isn't this enough?

Comment: Why not give it a try and lemme know.

Comment: @Kirubel, unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: It's probably a certificate problem in your server

Comment: @jcesarmobile even I think so. I tested url with SSL checker and `Intermediate CA` was not properly configured. I have asked server person to fix this. i will check then to see if that fixes the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who in case stumble upon same issue,

*The issue was The SSL in my server was not properly configured.*

I checked via https://www.sslshopper.com and the `Intermediate CA` was not properly configured.

After fixing this issue in the server, the app worked flawlessly on android device as well.